# Printing Report in MS Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am very new to Access and need a bit help over here. I was working on MS Access 2007 (in VB) with SQL 2008 Server as my database.

I am printing a report already saved on the Button Click event.
Everything is working fine, report can be printed but after printing the report it is also printing the form containing that Button.
Here is the code that I have written on Button_click:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName"
DoCmd.PrintOut
```

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

[DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> expression.OpenReport(ReportName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition,
>   WindowMode, OpenArgs)

```
DoCmd.OpenReport, "report", acViewNormal
```

You should not need  PrintOut.

Comment: Yes !! DoCmd.PrintOut not required !! Thank you so much !! :)